# Passando uma string de Conexão de forma dinâmica

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, lista, combobox, visual-studio-2017

Bem o meu problema seria tentar passar uma string de conexão a partir de um arquivo txt. que e usado também para trazer os itens do meu ComboBox, o objetivo e trazer um banco diferente dependendo do item selecionado no ComboBox. Tentei passar a string pelo arquivo e fazer a conexão do banco receber como parâmetro os itens do meu ComboBox, mas no momento que clico no botão para buscar aparece SYSTEM.NULLREFERENCEEXEEPTION.

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateInicial.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        dateFinal.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        textBox1.MaxLength = 20;

        comboBanco.Items.Clear();
        List<Planta> plantas = new List<Planta>();

        using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Conexoes\Estados.txt"))
        {
            string linha;
            while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(':');

                var planta = new Planta();
                planta.Local = espaçoArquivo[0];
                planta.Banco = espaçoArquivo[1];


                plantas.Add(planta);
            }

        }

        foreach (Planta result in plantas)
        {
            comboBanco.Items.Add(result);
        }
        comboBanco.DisplayMember = "Local";

    }

    private void comboBanco_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBanco.SendToBack();
        FrmGrid formb = new FrmGrid();

        switch (((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local)
        {
            case "CT":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                comboBanco.SelectedValue = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Banco;
                break;

            case "CU":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                break;

            case "AT":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection conn;

            conn = new OdbcConnection(comboBanco.SelectedValue.ToString());

            MessageBox.Show(conn.State.ToString());

            conn.Open();

            MessageBox.Show(conn.State.ToString());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OdbcDataAdapter ada = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();

            string sql = "   SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ROWNUM <=50 ";

            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            ada = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            ada.Fill(dt);

            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            FrmGrid c = new FrmGrid();
            c.Show();
            c.grdRelatorio.DataSource = dt;
            c.grdRelatorio.Refresh();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        class Planta
       {
         public string Local { get; set; }
         public string Banco {get; set;}
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Será que não falta preencher a propriedade `Conexao` quando está a preencher a lista `plantas`?

Comment: A deslize meu, a propriedade Conexao estava sendo usada apenas para dar valor a uma label, esquece de tirar ela ali no exemplo

Comment: Sendo assim acho que basta colocar o `ValueMember` da `ComboBox` como "Banco" (onde antes tinha "Conexao").

Comment: Tentei sua dica, mas o erro continua sendo o mesmo

Comment: Ao fazer o _click_ no botão, que valor tem o `SelectedItem` da `ComboBox`? Está a `null`?

Comment: Eu não defini nenhum valor no SelectedItem no click do botão, seria esse o problema ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82364/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-gabriel-miranda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no `SelectedValue`, que fica a `null` quando clica no botão.

A solução passa por obter a instância da classe `Planta` e obter o valor por lá.

No `Form_Load` pode otimizar ligeiramente o seu código:

```
using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Conexoes\Estados.txt"))
{
    string linha;
    while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(':');

        var planta = new Planta()
        {
            Local = espaçoArquivo[0],
            Banco = espaçoArquivo[1]
        };

        plantas.Add(planta);
        comboBanco.Items.Add(planta);
    }
}

comboBanco.DisplayMember = "Local";
comboBanco.ValueMember = "Banco";
```

Depois, no evento `button1_Click` vai buscar a instância e pega na propriedade `Banco`:

```
Planta planta = comboBanco.SelectedItem as Planta;
conn = new OdbcConnection(planta?.Banco);
```

Penso que dessa forma resolve o seu problema!